# How can I dynamically resize a header view in a UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have header (a UICollectionReusableCell) in a UICollectionView whose height needs to be variable. How can I have it resize itself according to the height of its contents?

I do *not* need to support iOS 7, and Autolayout solutions are preferable (if they exist).

Comment: You can try doing this without the XIB file as explained in here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42367674/1306884

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is how I solved it. I wish it was more elegant.

1. Set the `UILabel` in the header view to have a `numberOfLines` value of 0. This will let it resize itself.
2. Move the header out of the storyboard and into a xib.
3. In `collectionView(_:layout:referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:)` instantiate a header from the xib. We'll use it to compute a size.
4. Set the header to the desired width (in my case the width of the collection view), and configure it with the desired text and images
5. Call `setNeedsLayout` and `layoutIfNeeded`.
6. Use `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)` to compute the height.
7. Return the height and width as CGSize

Notes:

- The header must be moved out of the storyboard and into a xib because calling `dequeuReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind` from `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)` causes a crash.
- The header view must be able to compute a correct height only knowing its content and the desired width. This took some fiddling with the constraints.

Comment: This almost worked for me. Instead of setting the frame/bounds I had to create and add a width constraint. before calling systemLayoutSizeFittingSize

Comment: Thank you. Also, if you are care about performance and you use only one section with one header, it is possible to move header initialisation into`viewDidLoad` instead of `collectionView(_:layout:referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:)`.

Answer (score -2):

Here would be my approach -

1. Create outlets for your header and your contents.
2. Get the height of your contents
3. Set the height of your header as a % of the contents

In your View Controller -

```
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = yourCollectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("YourCustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! YourCustomeCell
    ...
    cell.setUpCell()
    return cell
}
```

In your View Cell -

```
@IBOutlet weak var headerView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var contentView: UIView!
func setUpCell() {
    let percentageYouWant = 0.3
    let newFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: contentView * percentageYouWant, height: contentView * percentageYouWant)
    headerView.frame = newFrame
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. My header is a UICollectionReusableView, not part of a UICollectionViewCell. I've edited my question to try to make it more clear.